# how do I use layouts in java without elements overlapping?

Tags: java, layout, jmenu

I want to have my menubar and help bar appear next to each other but if they both share the same position they overlap, how do i get them to sit next to each other?

```
        add(menuBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(helpBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Comment: Menu bars use their own layout. You shouldn't be using these BorderLayout constraints as you're currently attempting.

Answer (score 0):

The standard UI for a frame it to have a:

1. Title bar
2. Menu bar
3. Tool bar

displayed vertically.

So the standard code would be:

```
frame.setJMenuBar( menuBar );
frame.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.Page_START);
```

If you really want the menuBar and toolBar to display on the same line then you would need to add the toolBar to the menuBar.

The code might be something like:

```
menuBar.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );
menuBar.add( toolBar );
```

Now the toolBar will appear on the right side of the frame.

If you want the toolBar right beside the menuBar then try:

```
menuBar.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut(10) );
menuBar.add( toolBar );
```